# Setup of Scala/Flink project using Bazel

Tags: scala, sbt, apache-flink, bazel

I am trying to setup a simple flink application from scratch using Bazel. I've bootstrapped the project by running

```sh
sbt new tillrohrmann/flink-project.g8
```

and after that I have added some files in order for Bazel to take control of the building (i.e., migrate from sbt). This is how the `WORKSPACE` looks like

```py
# WORKSPACE
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

skylib_version = "1.0.3"
http_archive(
    name = "bazel_skylib",
    sha256 = "1c531376ac7e5a180e0237938a2536de0c54d93f5c278634818e0efc952dd56c",
    type = "tar.gz",
    url = "https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/releases/download/{}/bazel-skylib-{}.tar.gz".format(skylib_version, skylib_version),
)

rules_scala_version = "5df8033f752be64fbe2cedfd1bdbad56e2033b15"

http_archive(
    name = "io_bazel_rules_scala",
    sha256 = "b7fa29db72408a972e6b6685d1bc17465b3108b620cb56d9b1700cf6f70f624a",
    strip_prefix = "rules_scala-%s" % rules_scala_version,
    type = "zip",
    url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_scala/archive/%s.zip" % rules_scala_version,
)

# Stores Scala version and other configuration
# 2.12 is a default version, other versions can be use by passing them explicitly:
load("@io_bazel_rules_scala//:scala_config.bzl", "scala_config")
scala_config(scala_version = "2.12.11")

load("@io_bazel_rules_scala//scala:scala.bzl", "scala_repositories")
scala_repositories()

load("@io_bazel_rules_scala//scala:toolchains.bzl", "scala_register_toolchains")
scala_register_toolchains()

load("@io_bazel_rules_scala//scala:scala.bzl", "scala_library", "scala_binary", "scala_test")

# optional: setup ScalaTest toolchain and dependencies
load("@io_bazel_rules_scala//testing:scalatest.bzl", "scalatest_repositories", "scalatest_toolchain")
scalatest_repositories()
scalatest_toolchain()

load("//vendor:workspace.bzl", "maven_dependencies")
maven_dependencies()

load("//vendor:target_file.bzl", "build_external_workspace")
build_external_workspace(name = "vendor")
```

and this is the `BUILD` file

```py
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

load("@io_bazel_rules_scala//scala:scala.bzl", "scala_library", "scala_test")

scala_library(
    name = "job",
    srcs = glob(["src/main/scala/**/*.scala"]),
    deps = [
        "@vendor//vendor/org/apache/flink:flink_clients",
        "@vendor//vendor/org/apache/flink:flink_scala",
        "@vendor//vendor/org/apache/flink:flink_streaming_scala",
    ]
)
```

I'm using [bazel-deps](https://github.com/johnynek/bazel-deps) for vendoring the dependencies (put in the `vendor` folder). I have this on my `dependencies.yaml` file:

```yaml
options:
  buildHeader: [
      "load(\"@io_bazel_rules_scala//scala:scala_import.bzl\", \"scala_import\")",
      "load(\"@io_bazel_rules_scala//scala:scala.bzl\", \"scala_library\", \"scala_binary\", \"scala_test\")",
  ]
  languages: [ "java", "scala:2.12.11" ]
  resolverType: "coursier"
  thirdPartyDirectory: "vendor"
  resolvers:
    - id: "mavencentral"
      type: "default"
      url: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/
  strictVisibility: true
  transitivity: runtime_deps
  versionConflictPolicy: highest

dependencies:
  org.apache.flink:
    flink:
      lang: scala
      version: "1.11.2"
      modules: [clients, scala, streaming-scala] # provided
    flink-connector-kafka:
      lang: java
      version: "0.10.2"
    flink-test-utils:
      lang: java
      version: "0.10.2"
```

For downloading the dependencies, I'm running

```sh
bazel run //:parse generate -- --repo-root ~/Projects/bazel-flink-scala --sha-file vendor/workspace.bzl --target-file vendor/target_file.bzl --deps dependencies.yaml
```

Which runs just fine, but then when I try to build the project

```sh
bazel build //:job
```

I'm getting this error

```
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/salvalcantara/Projects/me/bazel-flink-scala/WORKSPACE", line 44, column 25, in <toplevel>
        build_external_workspace(name = "vendor")
    File "/Users/salvalcantara/Projects/me/bazel-flink-scala/vendor/target_file.bzl", line 258, column 91, in build_external_workspace
        return build_external_workspace_from_opts(name = name, target_configs = list_target_data(), separator = list_target_data_separator(), build_header = build_header())
    File "/Users/salvalcantara/Projects/me/bazel-flink-scala/vendor/target_file.bzl", line 251, column 40, in list_target_data
        "vendor/org/apache/flink:flink_clients": ["lang||||||scala:2.12.11","name||||||//vendor/org/apache/flink:flink_clients","visibility||||||//visibility:public","kind||||||import","deps|||L|||","jars|||L|||//external:jar/org/apache/flink/flink_clients_2_12","sources|||L|||","exports|||L|||","runtimeDeps|||L|||//vendor/commons_cli:commons_cli|||//vendor/org/slf4j:slf4j_api|||//vendor/org/apache/flink:force_shading|||//vendor/com/google/code/findbugs:jsr305|||//vendor/org/apache/flink:flink_streaming_java_2_12|||//vendor/org/apache/flink:flink_core|||//vendor/org/apache/flink:flink_java|||//vendor/org/apache/flink:flink_runtime_2_12|||//vendor/org/apache/flink:flink_optimizer_2_12","processorClasses|||L|||","generatesApi|||B|||false","licenses|||L|||","generateNeverlink|||B|||false"],
Error: dictionary expression has duplicate key: "vendor/org/apache/flink:flink_clients"
ERROR: error loading package 'external': Package 'external' contains errors
INFO: Elapsed time: 3.644s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
```

Why is that? Anyone can help? It would be great having detailed instructions and project templates for Flink/Scala applications using Bazel. I've put everything together in the following repo: https://github.com/salvalcantara/bazel-flink-scala, feel free to send a PR or whatever.

Comment: Which version of Bazel are you using?

Comment: `bazel 4.0.0-homebrew`